# how to get response from post in javaws playframework 2.5

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.5, java-ws

please help me, i want send json data to some API which use basic auth and i want catch respon from that API. this is my code:

```
@Inject
WSClient ws;
public Result testWS(){
JsonNode task = Json.newObject()
            .put("id", 123236)
            .put("name", "Task ws")
            .put("done", true);

WSRequest request = ws.url("http://localhost:9000/json/task").setAuth("user", "password", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(task);
return ok(request.tojson);
```

the question is how i get return from ws above and process it to json? because that code still error. i'm use playframework 2.5

Answer (score 0):

`.post(task)` results in a `CompletionStage<WSResponse>`, so you can't just call `toJson` on it.  You have to get the eventual response from the completion stage (think of it as a promise).  Note the change to the method signature too.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.ws.WSAuthScheme;
import play.libs.ws.WSClient;
import play.libs.ws.WSResponse;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor;

@Singleton
public class FooController extends Controller {

    private final WSClient ws;
    private final ExecutionContextExecutor exec;

    @Inject
    public FooController(final ExecutionContextExecutor exec,
                           final WSClient ws) {
        this.exec = exec;
        this.ws = ws;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
        final JsonNode task = Json.newObject()
                                  .put("id", 123236)
                                  .put("name", "Task ws")
                                  .put("done", true);

        final CompletionStage<WSResponse> eventualResponse = ws.url("http://localhost:9000/json/task")
                                                               .setAuth("user",
                                                                        "password",
                                                                        WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
                                                               .post(task);

        return eventualResponse.thenApplyAsync(response -> ok(response.asJson()),
                                               exec);
    }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS) for more details of working with asynchronous calls to web services.

Comment: the colour of "map" and "toJson". and when i run it. show error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method map((response)[...]Json))
  location: variable eventualResponse of type java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<play.libs.ws.WSResponse>

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this from memory using the old `F.Promise` API in my head.  I've updated the answer with the correct method call.

Comment: there still an error, AsyncController : invalid method declaration; return type required